# What is the meaning of "get over" in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "get over" in the following sentence (Source: PHONICS PC COMICS Volume 3 Issue 1),

> You two really grew a lot this year. I cannot **get over** how tall
>   you both are. The doctor will be amazed at my two big boys!

?

Does "I cannot **get over** how tall you both are" mean "I cannot know how tall you both are" or "I cannot overcome how tall you both are"?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we clearly have the British usage. One of the meanings of 'get over' is to fully understand, realise, or become used to something, especially a change. I can't get over how big your dog is now. I can't get over how quiet the house is, now that the kids have left home. There is not necessarily any implication of worry, disquiet or disappointment.

Very often, the expression is a kind of exaggeration - of course we have got over  (or will soon get over) the fact that a child we saw a year ago is now noticeably taller.

> **4. (intr, preposition) to appreciate fully
>
>    I just can't get over seeing you again**

[Get over in British (Collins Dictionary)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/get-over)